# rails 4 strong params ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I cant seem to find the problem.
In my Admin::CompetitionsController < ApplicationController I do

```
  def create
      respond_to do |format|
          if @competition.save(competition_params)
              format.html {
                  flash[:success] =  'Success!'
                  redirect_to competition_path
              }
          else
              format.html {
                  render :action => 'edit'
              }
          end
      end
  end
def competition_params
    params.require(:competition).permit(:name, :date, :sex, :category, :country_id, :description, :article, :result)
end
```

My migration looks like this:

```
  create_table :competitions do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.date :date
      t.integer :sex
      t.integer :category
      t.integer :country_id
      t.string :article
      t.string :result
      t.string :description
    end
```

And this is my form:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @competition], :html => {:class => "form"} do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :date %>
      <%= f.date_select :date, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label "Gender" %>
      <%= f.select "sex", options_for_select(@sex), :class => 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :category %>
      <%= f.select "category", options_for_select(@category), :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.select :country_id, Country.all.collect { |country| [country.name, country.id] },
                   { :prompt => "Select Country" } %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_area :description, :class => 'form-control', :rows=>5 %>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :article %>
      <%= f.text_field :article, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :result %>
      <%= f.text_field :result, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>



    <%= f.submit :class=>'btn btn-primary'  %>
<% end %>
```

The request parameters I get:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"hFayDADwjR0ZfhKZfnHKbzJntwDrzHiZ/3H61LcJsEA=",
 "competition"=>{"name"=>"",
 "date(1i)"=>"2013",
 "date(2i)"=>"11",
 "date(3i)"=>"22",
 "sex"=>"1",
 "category"=>"1",
 "country_id"=>"",
 "description"=>"",
 "article"=>"",
 "result"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Create Competition"}
```

And every time I get the ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError. I tried permiting different parameters with no success. I don't know what to try anymore.

The full error page:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in Admin::CompetitionsController#create
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Rails.root: /home/linux/RubymineProjects/Tabor

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
activemodel (4.0.0) lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:21:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/core.rb:192:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:85:in `build_resource'
cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:66:in `load_resource_instance'
cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__2070627161148806707__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3850854791608649842__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/linux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/linux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/linux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"N8DJKWtnMtunizyY4oGBuGNiL9UNIc63sM2PHWxpXtY=",
 "competition"=>{"name"=>"",
 "date(1i)"=>"2013",
 "date(2i)"=>"11",
 "date(3i)"=>"22",
 "sex"=>"1",
 "category"=>"1",
 "country_id"=>"",
 "description"=>"",
 "article"=>"",
 "result"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Create Competition"}

Toggle session dump
_csrf_token: "N8DJKWtnMtunizyY4oGBuGNiL9UNIc63sM2PHWxpXtY="
session_id: "116666f7d0e5494da6a99d481c7e8cc8"
warden.user.user.key: [[1], "$2a$10$oe41UVUa5llNALpv5gIeXu"]

Toggle env dump
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.1"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip,deflate,sdch"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "sl-SI,sl;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
REMOTE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "0.0.0.0"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: You'll note that the date has been broken up to 3 components - that's likely the source of your problem...

Comment: Please post the output of the web server when you get the error.

Comment: Where are you instantiating the @competition?

Comment: I'm using cancan's load_and_authorize_resource before filter to create the instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your whitelist to handle the multi-part date parameter.:

```
def competition_params
  params.require(:competition).permit(:name, :"date(1i)", :"date(2i)", :"date(3i)", :sex, :category, :country_id, :description, :article, :result)
end
```

Also, this code doesn't look quite right:

```
if @competition.save(competition_params)
```

Assuming you already have a `Competition` instance assigned to `@competition` - you should use `update_attributes`:

```
if @competition.update_attributes(competition_params)
```

Otherwise, assign it first:

```
@competition = Competition.new(competition_params)
if @competition.save
```

Comment: I use load_and_authorize_resource from cancan, which uses a before filter to load the resource into an instance variable and authorize it for every action but yes it should be @ competition.save (without the (competition_params) ). It works nice on my other controllers. I did not know you can use a string as a hash unfortunately it did not work. (I also tried without load_and_authorize and putting @ competition = Competition.new(competition_params) as you suggested but I still get the same error

Comment: @user1116724: please post the exact error message (with stacktrace)

Comment: Ok I am not sure what happened. I tried to do it again without load_and_authorize and did the assignment as you said and now it works. I might have made a typo somewhere. I am still learning....

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by CanCan trying to assign attributes before your controller code does.  You will need to add a `before_action` to assign the new_user instead of doing it in your controller action.

Also make sure `create_and_authorize_resource` is **after** the `before_action`

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756469/cancan-load-and-authorize-resource-triggers-forbidden-attributes) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above worked for me. Here is an example of the code used for whoever needs it.

```
class WhateversController < ApplicationController
  before_action :cancan_rails4_hack
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def cancan_rails4_hack
     @event = Event.new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

CanCan doesn't work with Rails4. Use CanCanCan instead.

> By default, CanCan will try to sanitize the input on :create and
>   :update routes by seeing if your controller will respond to the
>   following methods (in order):
>
> create_params or update_params (depending on the action you are
>   performing) _params such as article_params (this is the
>   default convention in rails for naming your param method)
>   resource_params (a generically named method you could specify in each
>   controller) Additionally, load_and_authorize_resource can now take a
>   param_method option to specify a custom method in the controller to
>   run to sanitize input.

I have done the porting, just replace the line in Gemfile with:

```
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
```

Link here:https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan